# Gui canvas bar graph doesn't display list number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a GUI code that makes a graph based on the data. in the code it displays data then some numbers and based on the numbers it will change the height of the bar. The code all puts the data above the bar in the graph.

```
#Read text file and turn it into a nested list
def readfile():
    textlist = [line.split(',') for line in open("chookfood.txt", 'r')]
    return textlist

#makes 'l' a value to pull data from the text sheet. 
l = readfile()
print(l[0][1], l[0][2], l[1][1], l[1][2], l[3][1], l[3][2], l[4][1], l[4][2])
```

I get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   y0 = c_height - (y * y_stretch + y_gap)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Rest of code:

```
import tkinter as tk


#Read text file and turn it into a nested list
def readfile():
    textlist = [line.split(',') for line in open("chookfood.txt", 'r')]
    return textlist

#makes 'l' a value to pull data from the text sheet. 
l = readfile()
data = (l[0][1], l[0][2], l[1][1], l[1][2], l[3][1], l[3][2], l[4][1], l[4][2])


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Bar Graph")


c_width = 400  # Window's width
c_height = 350  # Window's height
c = tk.Canvas(root, width=c_width, height=c_height, bg='white')#White store
c.pack()

# Bar Graphing Scale
y_stretch = 1  # The highest y = max_data_value * y_stretch
y_gap = 25  # The gap between lower canvas edge and x axis
x_stretch = 16  # Stretch x wide enough to fit the variables
x_width = 20  # The width of the x-axis
x_gap = 20  # The gap between left canvas edge and y axis

# A quick for loop to calculate the rectangle
for x, y in enumerate(data):

    # coordinates of each bar

    # Bottom left coordinate
    x0 = x * x_stretch + x * x_width + x_gap

    # Top left coordinates
    y0 = c_height - (y * y_stretch + y_gap)

    # Bottom right coordinates
    x1 = x * x_stretch + x * x_width + x_width + x_gap

    # Top right coordinates
    y1 = c_height - y_gap

    # Draw the bar
    c.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="blue")

    # Put the y value above the bar
    c.create_text(x0 - 1, y0, anchor=tk.SW, text=str(y))

root.mainloop()
```

When `data = (1,2,3,4,5)` its fine but not with he other. How can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

data looks like a list of strings to me, which means that y is a string. File reading methods return strings, and you never convert it to int(). I suggest changing

```
print(l[0][1], ...
```

to

```
print(repr(l[0][1], ...
```

instead to show the problem, and changing

```
y0 = c_height - (y * y_stretch + y_gap)
```

to

```
y0 = c_height - (int(y) * y_stretch + y_gap)
```

(This will convert y to an int, so be careful if you want to support decimals.)